# How to add Android debug function (LOGE, LOGW...) in C++ inline member function?

Tags: android, c++, inline, member-functions

I'm developing Android audio driver. In case I need to add debug function "LOGD" inside constructor `Mutex::Autolock::Autolock(Mutex& mutex)`, which is defined in `"frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h"`

I have already include , but there are still compiling error:

> frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:244:1: error: macro "LOG" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1

I guess it's because the keyword `inline` blocks external macros, but not for sure.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to define LOGD like so:

```
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "my module name", __VA_ARGS__)
```

Remember you must `#include <android/log.h>` for this to work.

Comment: and add -llog to your LOCAL_LDLIBS